# Why this code which is posted on howstuffworks.com does not work?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{

int a[5];

int i;

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        a = i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a);
}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Please read [ask] a good question.

Comment: For one thing, the assignment `a = i;` makes no sense.  You probably want `a[i] = i;`.  Similarly, when printing it, `a` should be `a[i]`.  Then it will work.  Also, it seems you don't have any understanding of C, and are trying to get help debugging some code you found online.  I suggest learning at least the basics of C before trying to get help with a specific program.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays used as operand of operatiors except for `sizeof` and unary `&` are automatically converted to a pointer that points at the first element of the array.
The converted pointer is not a lvalue, so it cannot be used as the left operand of assignment operator.

This code works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[5];
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        a[i] = i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare `a` to be an array of integers - and instead of accessing an element of the array `a[i]` you access `a` directly, which only holds the memory adress of the first element of the array. So you are basically modifying memory adresses directly, which is almost never a good idea.

Comment: No, `a` *itself* doesn't hold the memory address, but `a` is *converted* to the address. *Arrays are not pointers.*

Answer (score -1):

yu have error in a =i, should a[i]=i:
    int main()

```
{

int a[5];

int i;

for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    a[i] = i;
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
}
```

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`: `%d` calls for `int`, but `a` is converted to `int*`.